# Mongodb findOneAndUpdate - check if new document added, or just updated

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have the following code which is finding and updating an employee-store record (if it exists, otherwise it creates one).

I have lots of employees in different stores, and they can choose to change store at any point (as long as the location is in America)

Below is my code so far:

```
    employee = await this.employeeStoreModel.findOneAndUpdate(
      { employee: employeeRecord._id, location: "America" },
      {
        employee: employeeRecord._id,
        store: employeeRecord.store,
        location: "America",
      },
      { new: true, upsert: true }
    );
```

This works correctly, however I am trying to return some messages from this based on what is being updated. It could be any of the following messages:

- If it's a completely new employee-store record being added, then return "{{StoreID}} has a new employee - {{EmployeeID}}"
- If it's a change of store on an existing employee-store record, then return "{{EmployeeID}} has changed from {{old StoreID}} to {{new StoreID}}"

Is this possible to do? Can anyone guide me on how I could start this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Options field,

```
rawResult: true
```

You must add the parameter.

The result will be as in the example below.

```
{ response:
     { n: 1,
       updatedExisting: false,
       upserted: 5e6a9e5ec6e44398ae2ac16a },
    value:
     { _id: 5e6a9e5ec6e44398ae2ac16a,
       name: 'Will Riker',
       __v: 0,
       age: 29 },
    ok: 1 }
```

Depending on whether there is an update or insert in the updatedExisting field, you can return any message you want.

Comment: TIL! But I think OP will need to also set `new: false` (or remove it since that seems to be the default) in order to satisfy the second use case of knowing the old store ID

Comment: @user20042973 is there a way to return both the old document and the new document? As I would need both for the second statament?

Comment: I don't think so, but I also don't think you need to. You seem to already know the new location (since it is part of the update, eg `store: employeeRecord.store`) right?

Comment: @user20042973 of course! Thank you. So, just to check if the raw result response updatedExisting is true, then it has been updated. If it is false, then it has been inserted new?

Comment: Sounds right to me. You can see in @Ridvan Can's what above (with the example from the documentation) that when a new item is inserted then the `upserted` field contains the `_id` value of the new document which matches the doc in the `value` field as well